# Change date format with format() in R

Tags: r, date

So here's a basic algorithm in R that prints out the dates between two dates.

```
initial_date <- as.Date(toString((readline(prompt = "Enter a starting date in the format year-month-day:"))))
final_date <- as.Date(toString((readline(prompt = "Enter a final in the format year-month-day:"))))
dates <- seq(final_date, initial_date, by = "-1 day")
rev(dates[dates > initial_date & dates < final_date])
max.print = length(dates)
print(dates)
```

I would like to modify it so that the dates are in the format month-day-year like this: nov 27 2008. So I add "format(dates, format="%b %d %Y")".

```
initial_date <- as.Date(toString((readline(prompt = "Enter a starting date in the format year-month-day:"))))
final_date <- as.Date(toString((readline(prompt = "Enter a final in the format year-month-day:"))))
dates <- seq(final_date, initial_date, by = "-1 day")
format(dates, format="%b %d %Y")
rev(dates[dates > initial_date & dates < final_date])
max.print = length(dates)
print(dates)
```

But this keeps printing the same output as the previous code. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few points being misunderstood here:

1. `format(dates, format="%b %d %Y")` might be formatting it the way you want it to look, but it is not being stored, so the next command using `dates` is using the object as it was before the call to `format(..)`. This as well as *most* R functions are *functional*, meaning that the effect of them is realized when it is stored in an object: calling the function itself has no side-effect. The "right" way to use `format` is to either print it right away (see far below) or to store it into the same or another variable. While **I do not recommend doing this**, a more functional use of this would have been

   ```r
   dates <- format(dates, format="%b %d %Y")
   ```
2. Ditto for `rev(dates[...])`: you need to use it immediately (as in `print(rev(...))`, i.e., the argument of an immediate function call) or store it somewhere else, such as

   ```r
   reversed_dates <- rev(dates[...])
   ```
3. In R, dates (proper `Date`-class) are number-like, so that one can safely make continuous-number comparisons such as `date1 < date2` and `date2 >= date3`, etc. However, if you accidentally compare a `%Y-%m-%d`-**string** with another similary-formatted string, then it will still work. It still works because strings are compared *lexicographically*. This means that when comparing strings `"2020-01-01"` and `"2019-01-01"`, it will first compare `"2"` and `"2"`, it's a tie; same with `"0"`s; then it will see that `"2"` > `"1"`, and therefore `"2019-01-01"` comes before the other.

   This still works, even as strings, because the components with the most-significance are years, and as long as they are first in the string, the relative ordering (`>`, `sort`, `order`) still works. This continues to work if the dates are `0`-padded integers. This does *not* work if they are not `0`-padded, where `"2021-2-1" > "2021-11-1"` is reported as `TRUE`; this is because it gets to the month portion and compares the `"2"` with the first `"1"` of `"11"`, and does not see that the next digit makes the `"1"` greater than `"2"`.

   The moment one starts bringing in month *names*, this goes the same type of wrong, since the month names (in any language, perhaps?) are not ordered lexicographically (I don't know that this is an absolute truth, but it is certainly true in English and perhaps many/most western languages ... I'm not polyglot to speak for other languages). This means that `"2020-Apr-01" < "2020-Jan-01"` will again be `TRUE`, unfortunately.
4. We'll combine #3 with the fact that in general, R will always print a `Date`-class object as `"%Y-%m-%d"`; there is no (trivial) way to get it to print a `Date`-class object as your `"%b %d %Y"` without either (a) converting it to a string and losing proper ordering; or (b) [super-classing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69468780/3358272) it so that it presents like you want on the console, but it is still a number underneath.

   As for (a), this is a common thing to do for reports and labeling in plots, and I'm perfectly fine with that. *I am not trying to convince the world that it should always see a date as `%Y-%m-%d`.* However, what I am saying is that it is much easier to keep it as a proper `Date`-class object until you actually render it, and then `format` it at the last second. For this, do all of your filtering and ordering and *then* `print(format(..))`, such as this. ***I recommend this method.***

   ```r
   dates <- seq(as.Date("2020-02-02"), as.Date("2020-02-06"), by = "day")
   dates <- rev(dates[ dates > as.Date("2020-02-03") ])
   print(format(dates, format = "%b %d %Y"))
   # [1] "Feb 06 2020" "Feb 05 2020" "Feb 04 2020"
   ```

   Again, **above is the technique I recommend**.

   As for (b), *yes*, you can do it, but this approach is *fragile* since it is feasible that some functions that want `Date`-class objects will not immediately recognize that these are close enough to continue working as such; or they will strip the new class we assign at which point it will resort to `"%Y-%m-%d"`-format. You can use this, which requires that you change the class (see the `# important` line) of every `Date`-object you want to personalize the formatting. ***I recommend against doing this.***

   ```r
   format.myDATE <- function(x, ...) {            # fashioned after format.Date
     xx <- format.Date(x, format = "%b %d %Y")
     names(xx) <- names(x)
     xx
   }
   print.myDATE <- function(x, max = NULL, ...) { # fashioned after print.Date
     if (is.null(max))
       max <- getOption("max.print", 9999L)
     if (max < length(x)) {
       print(format.myDATE(x[seq_len(max)]), ...)
       cat(" [ reached 'max' / getOption(\"max.print\") -- omitted", 
         length(x) - max, "entries ]\n")
     } else if (length(x))
       print(format.myDATE(x), ...)
     else cat(class(x)[1L], "of length 0\n")
     invisible(x)
   }
   dates <- seq(as.Date("2020-02-02"), as.Date("2020-02-06"), by = "day")
   class(dates) <- c("myDATE", class(dates))      ## important!
   dates <- rev(dates[ dates > as.Date("2020-02-03") ])
   print(dates)                                   ## no need for format!
   # [1] "Feb 06 2020" "Feb 05 2020" "Feb 04 2020"
   ### and number-like operations still tend to work
   diff(dates)
   # Time differences in days
   # [1] -1 -1
   ```

   Again, ***I recommend against doing this*** for data that you are working with. Many packages that pretty-print tables and plots and such may choose to override our preference for formatting, so there is no guarantee that this is honored across the board. This is why I suggest "accepting" the R way while working with it, regardless of your locale, and formatting it for your aesthetic preferences immediately before printing/rendering.

Another couple minor points:

- remove `toString`, it's doing nothing for you here I think;
- your use of `max.print = ...` suggests you think this is going to change anything else; most R things that have global options use `options(...)` for this, so you need to either set it globally in this R session with `options(max.print=length(dates))`, or a one-time limit with `print(dates, max = length(dates))`.